# Search option for entire site?

Tags: search

I would like to search the specific keyword in all fields of all channels in Expression Engine. As there is only one excerpt option for each channel, I couldn't apply it to all fields in channel. Any option available to make all channel fields marked as excerpt to search entire site?

Answer (score 2):

The field you choose per-channel to use as an excerpt only determines what will be used to generate the contents of the `{excerpt}` variable inside the `{exp:search:search_results}` tag. It has no effect on whether a field is actually searched by the module.

All fields from all channels can be included in search by setting the **Is field searchable?** option to **Yes** on that field's **Edit Field** screen.

Also make sure that you set the `search_in` parameter on the `{exp:search:simple_form}` tag to either `everywhere` or `entries`, as it defaults to only searching `titles`.

Comment: @Derek: I dont want to mention channel field names in search result page. Is there any way to put unique field(searching field) name instead of putting {excerpt}?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display only the specific channel field in which the keywords were found? This cannot be done with the Search module.

Answer (score 0):

... You can make all fields searchable. Not just excerpts. If you go to your field group, and edit any particular field, you can just set this setting:

[image]

LOL, but set that settings to `Yes` and save the field group. TADA!

Answer (score 0):

You can use most custom fields in search results:

```
{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}
{custom_field_one}
{my_custom_field}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Bear in mind that if you are searching channels with different field groups you'll need to account for any custom field you want to show in the results.